# Image and text duplicating in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-8

I've been making an about us page in laravel 8. The page retrievs data from mysql in order for it to display on the front-end page of the website. The about page should display an image and some text besides it. Then below it, another text and image should appear. When I try to run the code, the image and the text duplicates itself as shown here : [image]. Here the code that I've written that's supposed to display two different images and text.

```
<div class="site-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center mr-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6 py-5 px-5">
        <img src="{{asset($about->image)}}" class="img-fluid rounded" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 pl-lg-5 ">
      <h3 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold py-2">{{$about->title}}</h3>
        <p class="text-justify pt-0 mr-5">{{$about->description}}</p>
        <p class="text-justify pt-0 mr-5">{{$about->sentence}}.</p>
        
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="site-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center mr-5">
      <div class="col-lg-6 pl-lg-5 ">
        <p class="text-justify pt-3 mr-5">{{$about->description}}</p>
        <p class="text-justify pt-3 mr-5">{{$about->sentence}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 py-5 px-5">
        <img src="{{asset($about->image)}}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my page to have an alternating layout exactly like shown in this codepen example, excluding the button. Can someone please guide on how I can achieve this layout. Here's a pic of the page data on mysql db.[image: DB Image]

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'sentence' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max: 4048',
        "photo" => 'required',
        'paragraph' => 'required',
        'segment' => 'required',
        
    ]);
    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $image_path = public_path('images/abouts/').$about->image;
        if(File::exists($image_path)){
        unlink($image_path);
        }
        $file = $request->image;
        $imageName = "images/abouts".time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path("images/abouts/"),$imageName);
        $about->image = $imageName;
        }
        $title = $request->title;
        $about->update([
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'sentence' => $request->sentence,
        'image' => $about->image,
        "photo" => 'required',
        'paragraph' => 'required',
        'segment' => 'required',
        'id'=>$request->id,
        
        
        
        ]);
```

**Migrations**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('abouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('image');
        $table->text('photo');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->longText('sentence');
        $table->longText('paragraph');
        $table->longText('segment');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**About View**

```
public function index()
{
    
    return view('/about')->with([
        'abouts' => About::all(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're fetching those rows and passing them to the view? You only seem to be using one object, instead of a loop to iterate over a collection of your data, which explains why the data shown is duplicated.

Comment: I've updated the question and updated code from my controller

Comment: I think that controller code is to update a specific about item. Can you show the controller code that is responsible for rendering the about view with its items? Or do you fetch the about items inside the view?

Comment: I'm fetching the page using the About controller. I've updated the code and placed the code which is supposed to render the view

Comment: Is there a way that a can avoid the duplication from occurring? I have placed all the data under one table, and everything was working well.

Comment: You only seem to be using one object, instead of a loop to iterate over a collection of your data,

Comment: Ok. Let me look at it & make the corrections